# I need to work out a way to output the total from a list based on items

Tags: grouping

as an example I have a list with "flt Num" (flight Number) and "Weight" (PAX Weight). The weight is collected from 1 of 4 scales at checkin. The flight number is created after booking according to weight so as not to exceed take off weight.

```
FLT Num   Weight
   13        87
   13        57
   14        74
   14        84
   14        45
```

the output I require is

```
Flt Num 13  144 2
Flt Num 14  203 3
```

the end number is total pax

Comment: What you are asking is quite confusing. But what is think you are looking for is a calculated field.

Comment: So this is for a checkin list at a helicopter charter business. The end output that I require is so the pilot can see on his iPhone a simple view with just the total weight of the passengers and the number of passengers per Flight number

Comment: Are you on SharePoint online? or 2013?

Comment: SharePoint online

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this is to create a view in classic experience where you group on flight number and configure the view to use Sum on Weight and count on FLT Num.

**Unfortunately modern experience does not yet support the use of totals in the modern views.**

[image]

You create the view by grouping on FLT Num and then add Totals on the fields FLT Num and Weight.

See the following image that displays the configuration of Totals.

[image]

What you then can do is to connect your list to excel for further calculations and filterings in a workbook.